# Safely Unload / Reload C++ dll in Python 2.7 (Replace dll with a new version)

Tags: python, c++, windows

I ask this question in the context of most other questions being 5-10 years old on this topic and given the following

- Windows 7 OS
- Several versions of a `.pyd` compiled dll at different file path locations e.g.

  - `/ver1.0/lib/my_dll.pyd`
  - `/ver1.1/lib/my_dll.pyd`
- `my_dll.pyd` is imported from a secondary file as `from my_dll import *`, I am not in control of the method or at liberty to alter

I can successfully switch between two `.pyd` versions as follows

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'\path\to\ver_1.0')
import my_dll                    # imports ver 1.0
print my_dll.release_version()
sys.path.pop(-1)
del sys.modules['my_dll']        # remove module dict ref
from IPython import get_ipython  # just in case you run in iPython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf') # need to remove history!
del my_dll                       # delete the import object

import _ctypes                   # release the library handle
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.CDLL('my_dll.pyd')
_ctypes.FreeLibrary(dll._handle) # for some reason it needs to be
_ctypes.FreeLibrary(dll._handle) # done twice.

sys.path.append(r'\path\to\ver_1.1')
import my_dll
print my_dll.release_version()
```

The failures of `reload` are overcome by reloading the C++ `.pyd` as per the following output

```
Version 1.0
Version 1.1
```

my issue is that then I am left with an extremely flimbsy python ecosystem that will crash at almost any new function call.

Is there a more updated methodology of doing this?

## References

- [ctypes unload dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128995/ctypes-unload-dll)
- [How can I unload a DLL using ctypes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359498/how-can-i-unload-a-dll-using-ctypes-in-python/28610285)
- [forcing ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary() to reload library from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964033/forcing-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-to-reload-library-from-file)
- [Python runtime: recompiling and reusing C library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6717111/4013571)
- https://bugs.python.org/issue14597

Comment: Clarification: On of the key reasons this post differs to the references is that the import is fixed as `from my_dll import *` and I am unable to adjust this to try some of the other linked solutions

Comment: As an alternative you could create C++ "dll manager" that you will call from python and that will switch dlls (`LoadLibrary`/`FreeLibrary`) and forward python calls to these dlls.

Comment: I came here because I have the same problem. Developing pyd for app and I need to do A LOT OF RELOADS, lots of pain, have u found any working solution for unloading pyd so it can be reloaded? Im in python3