# ctypes unload dll

Tags: python, ctypes

I am loading a dll with ctypes like this:

```
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("someDll.dll");
```

When I am done with the library, I need to unload it to free resources it uses.  I am having problems finding anything in the docs regarding how to do this.  I see this rather old post: [How can I unload a DLL using ctypes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359498/how-can-i-unload-a-dll-using-ctypes-in-python).  I am hoping there is something obvious I have not found and less of a hack.

Comment: I have, but, from the post I referenced: "i don't know, but i doubt that this unloads the dll. i'd guess it only removes the binding from the name in the current namespace (as per language reference) "  I suspect this is true.  I am fairly sure the resource I need freed are still open.

Comment: Might be useful: [\[SO\]: forcing ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary() to reload library from file (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986803/4788546), [\[SO\]: Unload shared library inside ctypes loaded shared library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223168/4788546).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only truly effective way I have ever found to do this is to take charge of calling `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary`. Like this:

```
import ctypes

# get the module handle and create a ctypes library object
libHandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.LoadLibraryA('mydll.dll')
lib = ctypes.WinDLL(None, handle=libHandle)

# do stuff with lib in the usual way
lib.Foo(42, 666)

# clean up by removing reference to the ctypes library object
del lib

# unload the DLL
ctypes.windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(libHandle)
```

*Update:*

As of Python 3.8, `ctypes.WinDLL()` no longer accepts `None` to indicate that no filename is being passed. Instead, you can workaround this by passing an empty string.

See https://bugs.python.org/issue39243

Comment: My ctypes calls begin failing when I go down this route with this error: "ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (16 bytes in excess)" when I attempt to make a function call

Comment: What calling convention is your function meant to use? `WinDLL` means `stdcall`. Is your lib `cdecl`? If so use `ctypes.CDLL` instead.