# forcing ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary() to reload library from file

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have the following code

```
import ctypes
lib1 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./mylib.so")
# modify mylib.so (code generation and compilation) or even delete it
lib2 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./mylib.so")
```

The problem is that `lib2` refers to the original shared library, not the new one. If I delete mylib.so between the calls I get no error.

Using `ctypes._reset_cache()` does not help.

How can I tell `ctypes` to actually reload the library from the hard disk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I unload a DLL using ctypes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359498/how-can-i-unload-a-dll-using-ctypes-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how to instruct *ctypes* how to unload a library (didn't find a way on [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes), but that doesn't mean that there isn't one).

It can be done manually, by forcing the loader to (decrement the library's reference count and) unload it via [[Man7]: DLCLOSE(3P)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlclose.3p.html) (also read [[Man7]: DLOPEN(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) for additional info on loading / unloading libraries).

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int func0(int arg0)
{
    int alter_factor = 2;
    printf("From C - arg0: %d, alter_factor: %d\n", arg0, alter_factor);
    return arg0 * alter_factor;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def handle_dll(name=DLL_NAME):
    dll = cts.CDLL(name)
    func0 = dll.func0
    func0.argtypes = (cts.c_int,)
    func0.restype = cts.c_int
    return dll, func0


def main(*argv):
    dlclose_func = cts.CDLL(None).dlclose
    dlclose_func.argtypes = (cts.c_void_p,)
    dlclose_func.restype = cts.c_int

    dll, func0 = handle_dll()
    res = func0(42)
    print(res)
    dlclose_func(dll._handle)
    input("In another terminal, modify the C code (e.g. change `alter_factor`), recompile (gcc -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c), and when done press ENTER here... ")
    dll, func0 = handle_dll()
    res = func0(42)
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050964033]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.c  dll00.so
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python code00.py
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) [GCC 9.3.0] 064bit on linux
>
> From C - arg0: 42, alter_factor: 2
> 84
> In another terminal, modify the C code (e.g. change `alter_factor`), recompile (gcc -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c), and when done press ENTER here... 
> From C - arg0: 42, alter_factor: 3
> 126
>
> Done.
> ```

Related (more or less):

- [[SO]: Unload shared library inside ctypes loaded shared library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223168/4788546)
- [[SO]: What is the difference between ctypes.CDLL() and ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67058486/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)

Comment: That worked. Thanks. However, this method might provoke segmentation faults (which seems to be a matter of fact). Also, it should be noted, that one has to call dlclose_func multiple times if the lib was loaded multiple times.

Comment: Yes, trying to access a symbol from an unloaded library is *Undefined Behavior* (and expected to segfault sometimes). And also each `dlopen` call must have its `dlaclose` counterpart. But that's all knowledge related to loading/unloading libs.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying [CristiFatis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986803/7128154) a bit, I wrote a close-library function. The following code can be used to develop in your shared library and call it (in the most recent version) from python.

```
import ctypes
def ctypesCloseLibrary(lib):
    dlclose_func = ctypes.CDLL(None).dlclose
    dlclose_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
    dlclose_func.restype = ctypes.c_int

    dlclose_func(lib._handle)

if __name__== "__main__":
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./mylib.so')

    # do things with lib_MyClass

    ctypesCloseLibrary(lib)
```

Just call `ctypesCloseLibrary` when you want `lib` to be reloadable by `lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./mylib.so')`.