# What is the difference between ctypes.CDLL() and ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()?

Tags: python, ctypes

Both methods seem to work (for me), but it seems the `CDLL()` method returns an object that has a `_handle` attribute, which can be used to unload the library via `ctypes.windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary()` (at least on Windows - I don't yet know how to do that on Linux).

What are the differences between these two methods - why would I choose one over the other?

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to load and unload libraries on both Windows on Linux (because I have a 3rd party library that seems to get into a broken state sometimes - I'm hoping unloading/reloading will reset it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is well explained in [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes):

> *class* ctypes.**CDLL**(*name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None, use_errno=False, use_last_error=False, winmode=0*)
>        Instances of this class represent loaded shared libraries. Functions in these libraries use the standard C calling convention, and are assumed to return *int*.
>
> ...
>
> *class* ctypes.**LibraryLoader**(*dlltype*)
>
> ...
>
> **LoadLibrary**(*name*)
>       Load a shared library into the process and return it. This method always returns a new instance of the library.
>
> These prefabricated library loaders are available:
>
> ctypes.**cdll**
>       Creates [CDLL](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL) instances.

So, the 2<sup>nd</sup> form is just a convenience wrapper, there's absolutely no functional difference between them, as shown below:

- *Win*:

  > ```py
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q067049436]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
  > Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  > Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  > >>>
  > >>> import ctypes as cts
  > >>>
  > >>>
  > >>> k32_1 = cts.CDLL("kernel32.dll")  # 1.
  > >>> k32_21 = cts.cdll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")  # 2.1.
  > >>> k32_22 = cts.cdll.kernel32  # 2.2.
  > >>>
  > >>> k32_1, k32_21, k32_22
  > (<CDLL 'kernel32.dll', handle 7fff59100000 at 0x2335c444ee0>, <CDLL 'kernel32.dll', handle 7fff59100000 at 0x2335b44bc10>, <CDLL 'kernel32', handle 7fff59100000 at 0x2335c45a790>)
  > >>>
  > >>> type(k32_1), type(k32_21), type(k32_22)
  > (<class 'ctypes.CDLL'>, <class 'ctypes.CDLL'>, <class 'ctypes.CDLL'>)
  > >>>
  > >>> k32_1._handle == k32_21._handle == k32_22._handle
  > True
  > ```

  Technically, *WinDLL* (*windll*) should be used here, but since *Python* is *064bit* (*pc064*), *CDLL* (*cdll*) is also fine
- *Nix*:

  > ```
  > (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q067049436]> ll $(pwd)/../q074171783/*.so
  > -rwxr-xr-x 1 cfati cfati 16376 Oct 23 22:37 /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q067049436/../q074171783/dll00.so*
  > -rwxr--r-- 1 cfati cfati  9728 Oct 23 22:40 /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q067049436/../q074171783/dll00_wincopy.so*
  > lrwxrwxrwx 1 cfati cfati     8 Jan 11 10:50 /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q067049436/../q074171783/libdll00.so -> dll00.so*
  > (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q067049436]>
  > (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q067049436]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$(pwd)/../q074171783 python
  > Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47)
  > [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
  > Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  > >>>
  > >>> import ctypes as cts
  > >>>
  > >>>
  > >>> ld0_1 = cts.CDLL("libdll00.so")  # 1.
  > >>> ld0_21 = cts.cdll.LoadLibrary("libdll00.so")  # 2.1.
  > >>> #ld0_22 = cts.cdll.libdll00  # 2.2.
  > >>>
  > >>> ld0_1, ld0_21
  > (<CDLL 'libdll00.so', handle 11f9510 at 0x7fbb9576cca0>, <CDLL 'libdll00.so', handle 11f9510 at 0x7fbb95754eb0>)
  > >>>
  > >>> type(ld0_1), type(ld0_21)
  > (<class 'ctypes.CDLL'>, <class 'ctypes.CDLL'>)
  > >>>
  > >>> ld0_1._handle == ld0_21._handle
  > True
  > ```

  *#2.2.* (commented) doesn't work here, since the **file extension must be part** of the string passed to [[Man7]: DLOPEN (3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (otherwise it doesn't find it - maybe this could be worked around a *Ld* script?).
  The closest thing that I could find is `cts.cdll["libdll00.so"]` (but it still looks more related to the other options)

Use whatever suits you best. 
2<sup>nd</sup> form (*#2.2.*) is shorter (I suppose this is its purpose). 
*#1.* and *#2.1.* are the same (*#2.1.* is probably more explanatory (as it has *LoadLibrary*)) and they allow you to load a library from a custom path, or with an extension different than the default. Personally, *#1.* is the one I prefer.

For more details, you can take a look at [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (master) cpython/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py), especially the *LibraryLoader* at implementation which (*cdll* actually is, and) is easy to understand.

Just a heads-up (probably you already know what you're getting into): loading and unloading libraries can sometimes be tricky:

- [[SO]: forcing ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary() to reload library from file (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986803/4788546)
- [[SO]: Unload shared library inside ctypes loaded shared library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223168/4788546)

You might also want to check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall encountered when calling functions via *CTypes*.

Comment: Probably I'm confused here, but I was asking about cdll.LoadLibrary() specifically, which isn't mentioned in your answer. Your 'ct.cdll.kernel32' example doesn't involve loading an external library (I think it assumes it's already loaded). I did read that page, but am still confused.

Comment: My bad, I missed *LoadLibrary*. It's the same thing. Whether the lib is already loaded or not is not relevant. Anyway the simpler form calls *LoadLibrary*.