# libc dll file is missing on windows 10

Tags: python, c, windows, dll, libc

I'm trying to run this code in vscode for a school task, but I keep getting an error of a missing file 'libc.dll' I am somewhat confused of this file since I am new to this and not sure where to look for this file...
Can someone explain to me what does this error actually mean and why I can't locate the file?

```py
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL("libc.dll")

libc.printf("hello everybody\n".encode('ascii'))
```

The error I'm getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\2-3.py", line 3, in 
libc = CDLL("libc.dll")

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 376, in **init**
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Comment: Did you [rtfm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)?

Comment: Well you're the one trying to use the file libc.dll. Where is the file that you are trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[GNU]: The GNU C Library (glibc)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (if this is what your *libc.dll* refers to) states (**emphasis** is mine):

> The GNU C Library project provides the core libraries **for the GNU system and GNU/Linux systems**, as well as many other systems that use Linux as the kernel.

So, *LibC* is part of *Nix* world (which *Win* is not in).

*MS*'s equivalent is *CRT* (also referred to as *VCRT*, *MSVCRT*, *UCRT*, ...: [[MS.Learn]: Microsoft C runtime library (CRT) reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/c-run-time-library-reference)).
According to [[Python.docs]: ctypes - Loading dynamic link libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries) (**make sure to also read the notes**):

> Here are some examples for Windows. Note that `msvcrt` is the MS standard C library containing most standard C functions, and uses the cdecl calling convention.

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as cts
> >>> import sys
> >>>
> >>> sys.version
> '3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]'
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> crt = cts.CDLL("msvcrt")
> >>>
> >>> crt.printf
> <_FuncPtr object at 0x0000019AE5A48040>
> ```

You should also check:

- [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) (when **calling** *printf* (or any function as a matter of fact))

Note: I also tried (a while ago) your code on *Nix* emulators (*MSYS2*, *Cygwin*) but they didn't work. The only thing that would work for sure is *WSL2* ([[MS.Learn]: Install Linux on Windows with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)), as it has a genuine *Linux* kernel, but I'm not sure if that's relevant for you.

Comment: @SafelyFast: Depends on the definition of "better". [\[SO\]: What is the difference between ctypes.CDLL() and ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67058486/4788546).