# How to structure importing DLL more than once with ctypes and python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dll, ctypes

I am using ctypes and python3.

I have a class where I want to be able to call methods that use functions from the DLL so I load the DLL in that class **init** as follows and can access it from there.

```
class example():
    def __init__():
        self.library = ctypes.cdll(example.dll)

    def method_1(self):
        do_something = self.library.FUNCTION(etc...)
```

Which is all well and good, the DLL will be loaded on every instance and can be used. However I then have some other functions that are not in the class:

```
def func_outside_class():
    library = ctypes.cdll(example.dll)
    do_something_else = library.FUNCTION(etc)
```

So I have a few of these outside the class and I want to know whether it is bad practice to call cdll on the same lib more than once? It doesn't seem quite right to me. I could of course call it once and pass the instance to the functions/class instances on creation but i'd like to be able to import these for use elsewhere so I like that it's nicely contained.

Any ideas? Happy to be told this is fine but I can't help but think there is a more elegant solution.

Cheers!

Comment: It's fine.  The DLL is only loaded once into memory.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179325/unload-shared-library-inside-ctypes-loaded-shared-library/52223168#52223168 might help. Calling `cdll()` more than once, will have no effect on *.dll* side, it will only execute some code uselessly. One other way would be to make all the funcs methods in your class.