# Can I explicitly close a ctypes CDLL?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a Python 2.7 GUI for interacting with a C library. I do a bunch of setup in the GUI, then I press "go" button. Then, I'm looking at results and no longer need the library code. But I would like to keep all the GUI state while changing the library.

I import the `so` or `dll` with `ctypes`, which obviously opens the file for reading. But, I'd like to explicitly close the file in order to recompile and overwrite it. Then, when I press the "go" button again, I'd like to import the new version.

In the worst case scenario, I could copy the file to a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, but then I have handles open to dozens of files, none of which I can clean up.

Can I somehow explicitly close the file handle? Or, can I read the contents of the file into a `StringIO` object and somehow point `ctypes` at that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to close the handle to the DLL so it released first so you can work with the file, you need to get the handle of the library and then pass it to [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows, then you can do what you need with the DLL file:

```
from ctypes import *

file = CDLL('file.dll')

# do stuff here

handle = file._handle # obtain the DLL handle

windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(handle)
```

preview:

Here is a test DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {

  switch( fdwReason ) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      puts("DLL loaded");
    break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      puts("DLL unloaded");
    break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void function(void) {
  puts("Hello");
}
```

preview:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>>
>>> file = CDLL('file.dll')
DLL loaded
>>>
>>> # now it's locked
...
>>> file.function()
Hello
0
>>> windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(file._handle)
DLL unloaded
1
>>> # not it's unlocked
```

on Linux you use [`dlclose`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlclose) it would be:

```
from ctypes import *

file = CDLL('./file.so')

# do stuff here

handle = file._handle # obtain the SO handle

cdll.LoadLibrary('libdl.so').dlclose(handle)
```

Here is a similar shared object:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) void dlentry(void) {
  puts("SO loaded");
}

void function(void) {
  puts("Hello");
}

__attribute__((destructor)) void dlexit(void) {
  puts("SO unloaded");
}
```

preview:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> 
>>> file = CDLL('./file.so')
SO loaded
>>> 
>>> file.function()
Hello
6
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary('libdl.so').dlclose(file._handle)
SO unloaded
0
>>>
```

Comment: Can `libdl.so` unload itself too?

Comment: I doubt it.  The host app would spontaneously loose access to it.   I'm not even sure the DLL knows about the host's handle to it.

Comment: ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert