# Why static variable not released when using python to call c++ program

Tags: python, c++

I'm using C extension of Python and I met with a problem in passing strings from Python to C program. Take the following as an example:
The python code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from os import system

ls_str = [ ['a','b'] , ['c','d'] ]
for str1, str2 in ls_str:
    system('g++ -c -fPIC *.cpp -o test.o')
    system('g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -o test.so test.o')
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.so')
    lib.Test.argtypes = [c_char_p]
    x = create_string_buffer(str1)
    y = create_string_buffer(str2)
    val = lib.Test(x,y)
```

The `.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
int Test(char *str1, char *str2){
    static string string1 = str1, string2 = str2;
    // string string1 = str1, string2 = str2;
    cout << "str1 = " << str1 << endl;
    cout << "str2 = " << str2 << endl;
    cout << "string1 = " << string1 << endl;
    cout << "string2 = " << string2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I define the `string1` and `string2` as `static`, I got the following output:

```
str1 = a
str2 = b
string1 = a
string2 = b
str1 = c
str2 = d
string1 = a
string2 = b
```

Then I remove the `static`, the output becomes:

```
str1 = a
str2 = b
string1 = a
string2 = b
str1 = c
str2 = d
string1 = c
string2 = d
```

I find that in function, say `Test()`, when a variable is defined as `static`, its value will not change even if I call `Test()` multiple times from Python. But I used to think that every time a call from Python finishes, the function in C program will be released.
Why does this happens? Is it the target that `static` is designed for?
Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: It might help if i point out that you are not running a C++ *program*, but a C++ *library*.  That might seem like semantics, but the C++ runs in the same process as python - it is not a complete program (it has no `main()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. When declared `static`, they are **initialized once** at the first call to the function. When not `static`, they are initialized at every call to the function.

The function is not "released" unless the dynamic library is unloaded. I'm not sure `ctypes` allows explicitly unloading libraries. They should be unloaded when the refcount goes to zero, so try `del lib` after `lib.Test`.

See: [How can I unload a DLL using ctypes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359498/how-can-i-unload-a-dll-using-ctypes-in-python)

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer is what I hope to know. Also thank you for your instruction on how to unload the libraries. Thank you!