# Run nosetests as individual processes on each test to avoid interference

Tags: python, nose

Is there a way to tell nosetest to run each test as an individual process to avoid interference of multiple tests?

I'm [loading dlls via ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359498/how-can-i-unload-a-dll-using-ctypes-in-python) in certain tests and they seem to stay persistent in other tests where I don't want them to be.

I know that they could be removed in a teardown, but is there any other way so I don't have to manually do that?